# error input in remix

Tags: tokens, smart-contract-wallets

Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":3,"values":4}, value={"types":["address[]","address","uint256"],"values":["0x4aFAdd1E9B0a47E90A803A10A730CDD097447f5f","0x97dC0294CbD53798C74fC67272Ffb0F4aEa81C77","0x9C586816E89196FF639f11459cca795701fb6A67","1322168400000"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)

Comment: Hi there. We'll need to see your contract code to help further...

Comment: Hellor, here's the code:https://github.com/laronlineworld/ClaimToken/blob/main/ClaimToken.sol

Comment: Trying to fork this, I just need to create a token airdrop with claim button. But I can't deploy it on remix because of that problem.

Comment: Okay, that compiles fine for me (using compiler v0.4.18). When are you seeing the error? Compile time, or when you try to deploy it?

Comment: when I deploy the contract this is the error: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":3,"values":4}, value={"types":["address[]","address","uint256"],"values":["0x4d2130d9d20428dc249a1e938a0bcea4b5b9ac1a","0xac01f01f51f0bdd012c1838bd5cef330e6c7ffca","0x0f4ca92660efad97a9a70cb0fe969c755439772c","1322168400000"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)

Comment: The first argument to the constructor needs to be an array of addresses. This works for me -> `["0x4d2130d9d20428dc249a1e938a0bcea4b5b9ac1a","0xac01f01f51f0bdd012c1838bd5cef330e6c7ffca"],"0x0f4ca92660efad97a9a70cb0fe969c755439772c","1322168400000"`

Comment: Glad it works :-) I've added an answer in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the following argument types are expected by the constructor:

```
["address[]","address","uint256"]
```

You are passing:

```
"0x4aFAdd1E9B0a47E90A803A10A730CDD097447f5f","0x97dC0294CbD53798C74fC67272Ffb0F4aEa81C77","0x9C586816E89196FF639f11459cca795701fb6A67","1322168400000"
```

...which doesn't include an array of addresses. So you need to change to:

```
["0x4aFAdd1E9B0a47E90A803A10A730CDD097447f5f","0x97dC0294CbD53798C74fC67272Ffb0F4aEa81C77"],"0x9C586816E89196FF639f11459cca795701fb6A67","1322168400000"
```